# Import form from Qt Designer to my Project in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt

I created a Form with my Qt Designer. Now I want to import it to my Qt Creator Project but I couldn't find any Import-buttons...

Does anyone know how to import an existing file made with QT Designer to Qt Creator to my project? Or is there any way to copy everything I made with QT Designer to a Form in Qt Creator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the form you created by Qt-Designer is a file called `myform.ui`.

Just copy it into your Qt project, beside other files.

Then right-click on the project and choose "Add Existing Files...", select `myform.ui`.

That's all.

[image]