# Export Qt Designer window to Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, designer

I am working on a project on Qt, and I'm a total noob, so I don't know how to bind my Qt Creator code and my QT Designer window. 
I almost finished my code, so I began drawing my windows with qt designer.

Then I simply saved as .ui file, but whenever I try to go to a slot (in this case clicked() from a button) I get the error that the header file associated with the window does not exist.

How do I properly import my designed window?

Thank you very much
ANy help will be appreciated

Comment: So did you start creating your `.ui` file by simply opening Designer and start creating it? I fear that the `Go to slot` functionality requires doing everything from within Creator itself from the beginning (generating the matching `.cpp`, `.h` and `.ui`). Anyhow, you don't really *need* that functionality to hook up your UI with custom slots -- just follow the instructions here http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-a-ui-file.html

Comment: This question has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15577571/import-form-from-qt-designer-to-my-project-in-qt-creator/44087468#44087468

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @peppe, the best way is to go with Qt Creator from the start. You can copy/paste your designs if made on Qt Designer.

On Qt Creator go to

`File > New File > Qt > Qt Designer Class` and it will automatically generate the code.